# scala type mismatch in map function

Tags: scala

Newbie to Scala.
I encountered this error while compile the code.

```
Error:(84, 130) type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: Array[String]
  val mappingStr = "Mapping Strings: \n" + stringIndexers.map(r=>Array(r.getInputCol, r.labels.mkString(", "))).reduce(_+"\n"+_.mkString(": \n")) + "\n"
                                                                 ^
```

the hat char points at "Array" of my code.
I didn`t see any issue, can anyone help to explain why?

Comment: can you please format your code and error as well, so that its easier to read.

Comment: Please show what `stringIndexers` is.

Comment: I think the error is on the `.reduce(_+"\n"+_.mkString(": \n"))`, if  the 1st _ is Array, then it should fail, but I am not sure.

Comment: stringIndexers is an Array of StringIndexerModel

Comment: If you just want to print the labels for each input column, try: `stringIndexers.foldLeft("")((acc, r) => r.getInputCol + ":\n" + r.labels.mkString(", ") + "\n" + acc)`

Comment: @chunjef, your suggestion fit my intention, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `map` a list of some items into a list of `Array[String]`, because it's what `Array()` apparently returns for each element of `stringIndexers`.

Then you try to `reduce` this `List[Array[String]]` by `+`-ing `String`s. This expects `_` in `reduce` to be a `String`, but it is not, it's an `Array[String]`.

You should provide a way to convert your arrays into strings, or maybe flatten your list of arrays first, it's hard for me to tell which your intention is.